# Oauth 2.0 to vimeo using c#. Next step: uploading a video to vimeo

Tags: c#, javascript, oauth, vimeo

I've been doing a quite a bit of research on how to authenticate with vimeo.

Problem is, I have yet to find a decent solution with C#.

The wrappers I've found seems outdated and does not have an option to upload a video after authenticating.

Any suggestions on where i should start?

Would it be better/easier doing it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vimeo's new API (https://developer.vimeo.com/api) they use OAuth 2.0 which is MUCH easier.

Additionally, in either version of the API uploading does not need to be signed so you don't need an authentication library for that part. You need authentication until you get the upload url, upload your file without authentication, and then complete the file with authentication.

Comment: At vimeos site i have a accesstoken within "my apps". I found this at oauth 2.0. Do i use this accesstoken to upload my video? If so, can i use the following guide, and skip directly to step 4? https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

Comment: Correct, you can hard code that token into your app and all uploads will go to the same user account that created the app.